# Split long sentences reading from text file

Tags: c, text

I would like to split long sentences in a text into smaller ones, according to an arbitrary cut point. My approach considers whitespaces to count words. Given the input file `input.txt` with content:

```
ciao
ciao ciao
ciao ciao ciao ciao ciao ciao
ciao ciao ciao ciao
ciao ciao ciao
```

I expect:

```
ciao
ciao ciao
ciao ciao ciao 
ciao ciao ciao
ciao ciao ciao 
ciao
ciao ciao ciao
```

for cutpoint `3`.

I approached the problem with the following code:

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<ctype.h>                                      

/* MAIN */

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

        FILE *inp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
        char c;
        int word_counter = 0;

        while((c = fgetc(inp)) != EOF){

                printf("%c", c);

                if(isspace(c))
                        ++word_counter;
                /* Cutter */
                if(word_counter == 3){
                        printf("\n");
                        word_counter = 0;  /* counter to zero */
                } 
        }

        return 0;
}
```

That returns, as output:

```
ciao

ciao  ciao

ciao  ciao  ciao
```

I cannot get the reason of such behaviour. Should the code simply print an extra newline when the condition is met? Why is it skipping an entire sentence?

Comment: Is there a particular reason for such a rapid and lapidary downvote? Any suggestion would be appreciated, in order to produce better questions hopefully more useful for the community.

Comment: use "getline" in order to read the file line by line, use strtok in order to get the "word", then simply print until you reach your threshold. Only downside is that if your line have multiple space, it will merge them into one.

Comment: That code does not generate that output from the given input. Please fix the question to show the actual output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reset `word_counter` to zero after reading a newline.

Also, you are printing each `c` twice if `word_counter` != 3:

```
printf("%c", c);  // ** here

if(isspace(c))
        ++word_counter;
/* Cutter */
if(word_counter == 3){
        printf("\n");
        word_counter = 0;
}
else
        printf("%c", c);  // ** and here
```

Maybe try this instead (not tested):

```
while((c = fgetc(inp)) != EOF){

    if (isspace(c) && ++word_counter == 3 ) {
            printf("\n");
            word_counter = 0;  /* counter to zero */
            continue;
    } 
    if (c == '\n') {
        word_counter = 0;
    }
    printf("%c", c);
}
```

Even shorter:

```
while((c = fgetc(inp)) != EOF){

    if ( (isspace(c) && ++word_counter == 3) || (c == '\n') ) {
            printf("\n");
            word_counter = 0;  /* counter to zero */
            continue;
    } 
    printf("%c", c);
}
```

Also keep in mind that [isspace(c)](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/isspace/) will return `true` if `c == '\n'`, so a more robuust version which also handles `\r\n` would be:

```
while((c = fgetc(inp)) != EOF){

    if ( (c == ' ' || c == '\t') && (++word_counter == 3) ) {
        word_counter = 0;
        printf("\n");
        continue;
    }
    if ( c == '\r' || c == '\n' ) {
        word_counter = 0;
    }
    printf("%c", c);
}
```

Comment: Does not I, when it reach the cutpoint? Or should I reset it in a different moment?

Comment: You need to reset your word_counter to 0 when you encounter a '\n'.
You need to print your word only if "word_counter < 3"

Comment: Yeah I posted the wrong version of the code, thank you!